# Query certificate notification emails using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In our Azure AD tenant we have quite a few Enterprise applications. Some of these are set up to use SAML SSO, and when this is initially set up, the certificate notification email is set to the person setting up the application.

Is there a way to query this information (as in the emails used for certificate notifications) using Microsoft Graph API?